# How can I do this regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string :

```
line = "[kossor],(blommor),{skor},kossor,blommor,skor"
```

I want to write a pattern that matches the characters ()[] and {} and the words inside, like this:

```
['[kossor]', '(blommor)', '{skor}']
```

I used this method:

```
ligne = "[kossor],(blommor),{skor},kossor,blommor,skor"
pattern = "\(([^\)]+)\)" 
ANSWER = re.findall(pattern, ligne)
```

I got this :

```
["blommor"]
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: does the input line always has matching `() [] {}`? or can it have something like `(blommor]`? also, are all strings separated by `,`? for given sample ip/op, even a simple `re.findall(r'[\[({][^,]+', line)` would do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this pattern

```
pattern = r"([\[\(\{].*?[\]\)\}])"
```

**Code**

```
import re
pattern = r"([\[\(\{].*?[\]\)\}])"
ligne = "[kossor],(blommor),{skor},kossor,blommor,skor"
re.findall(pattern,ligne)
```

**Output**

```
 ['[kossor]', '(blommor)', '{skor}']
```

Comment: That doesn't work. If you inject a non matching string between any of what you are trying to match, that regex breaks. Try: `[kossor],(blommor), chicken, {skor},`, and I don't think that will work.

Comment: @idjaw updated the code for working with non-matching strings inside thanks

Comment: One last thing. Your output now should be: `['[kossor]', '(blommor)', '{skor}']`

Comment: @idjaw that was a typo. Now copy pasted from console .Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we want to be *strict*: we want to match `[abc]` and `(abc)`,
but not ill-formed things such as `[abc)`. We can use a regex like this:

```
pattern = r'\([^)]+\)|\[[^]]+\]|{[^}]+}'
```

Essentially saying, match `(...)`, or `[...]`, or `{...}`; but do not
match strings with mismatched bracket types.

This may lead to unwanted results. For example:

```
ligne = "[kossor],(blommor),{skor},kossor,blommor,skor,[abc),(abc]"
print(re.findall(pattern, ligne))
```

Result:

```
['[kossor]', '(blommor)', '{skor}', '[abc),(abc]']
```

Whether you want to capture such results or not depends on your data and
purpose. You could add `^,` to the character class to stop matching if
it hits a comma inside the brackets:

```
pattern = r'\([^),]+\)|\[[^],]+\]|{[^},]+}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following regex (character class):

```
In [10]: re.findall(r'[\[({][^\]})]+[\]}\)]', line)
Out[10]: ['[kossor]', '(blommor)', '{skor}']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sub and split:

```
 re.sub(r'(?<=\})(.*$)','',line).split(',')
 Out[23]: ['[kossor]', '(blommor)', '{skor}']
```